# How can I add a cookie to an existing cookielib CookieJar instance in Python?

Tags: python, cookies, mechanize, cookiejar, cookielib

I have a *CookieJar* that's being used with *Mechanize* that I want to add a cookie to. How can I go about doing this?

make_cookie() and set_cookie() weren't clear enough for me.

```
br = mechanize.Browser()
cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
br.set_cookiejar(cj)
```

Comment: There is a similar questions asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6878418/putting-a-cookie-in-a-cookiejar

Answer (score 37):

I managed to figure this out:

```
import mechanize
import cookielib

br = mechanize.Browser()
cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
br.set_cookiejar(cj)
ck = cookielib.Cookie(version=0, name='Name', value='1', port=None, port_specified=False, domain='www.example.com', domain_specified=False, domain_initial_dot=False, path='/', path_specified=True, secure=False, expires=None, discard=True, comment=None, comment_url=None, rest={'HttpOnly': None}, rfc2109=False)
cj.set_cookie(ck)
for index, cookie in enumerate(cj):
    print index, ' : ', cookie
```

Output:

```
0  :  <Cookie Name=1 for www.example.com/>
```

Comment: What is the conclusion? Is it an actual answer? Or a progress report?