# Python requests lib, is requests.Session equivalent to urllib2's opener?

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib2, python-requests

I need to accomplish a login task in my own project.Luckily I found someone has it done already.
Here is the related code.

```
import re,urllib,urllib2,cookielib

class Login():   
    cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()     
    opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))  

def __init__(self,name='',password='',domain=''):  
    self.name=name  
    self.password=password  
    self.domain=domain  
    urllib2.install_opener(self.opener)  

def login(self):  
    params = {'domain':self.domain,'email':self.name,'password':self.password}  
    req = urllib2.Request(  
        website_url,  
        urllib.urlencode(params)  
    )  

    self.openrate = self.opener.open(req)  

    print self.openrate.geturl()  
    info = self.openrate.read()
```

I've tested the code, it works great (according to `info`).
Now I want to port it to Python 3 as well as using [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) lib instead of urllib2.
My thoughts:

1. since the original code use `opener`, though not sure, I think its equivalent in `requests` is [`requests.Session`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#session-objects)
2. Am I supposed to pass in a `jar = cookiejar.CookieJar()` when making request? Not sure either.

I've tried something like

```
import requests
from http import cookiejar
from urllib.parse import urlencode

jar = cookiejar.CookieJar()
s = requests.Session()
s.post(  
    website_url,  
    data = urlencode(params),
    allow_redirects = True,
    cookies = jar  
)
```

Also, followed the answer in [Putting a `Cookie` in a `CookieJar`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6878418/putting-a-cookie-in-a-cookiejar), I tried making the same request again, but none of these worked.

That's why I'm here for help.
Will someone show me the right way to do this job? Thank you~

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. An opener and a `Session` are not entirely analogous, but for your particular use-case they match perfectly.
2. You do not need to pass a CookieJar when using a `Session`: Requests will automatically create one, attach it to the `Session`, and then persist the cookies to the `Session` for you.
3. You don't need to urlencode the data: requests will do that for you.
4. `allow_redirects` is `True` by default, you don't need to pass that parameter.

Putting all of that together, your code should look like this:

```
import requests

s = requests.Session()
s.post(website_url, data = params)
```

Any future requests made using the `Session` you just created will automatically have cookies applied to them if they are appropriate.

Comment: Thank you, I finally got it to work.It's having `urlencode` that caused the problem.BTW, you said "An opener and a Session are not entirely analogous", then what is the equivalent of opener?

Comment: There is no equivalent of opener, because Requests rejects the idea entirely. `Session`s are where Requests maintains state, so in that sense they _are_ like openers, but there's only ever one kind and it does all state maintenance: in that sense they are _unlike_ openers.