# alternative to curl functions

Tags: php, python, cookies, curl

Im a python beginner, so please sorry for my question.
I try to write a script in python, acutally the script use linux bash, python and php. This script was not written by me, so it is not easy to understand every point. I would do now everything in python, cause i think this is the better way and it should work then on every system, not only on linux.

I need the following line "translated" to python:

```
curl -s --cookie-jar "$COOKIE_DIR/$SAVE_COOKIE" -b "$COOKIE_DIR/$LOAD_COOKIE" --data "$QUERY_STRING" "$URL" > "$TEMP_FILE""_bak"
```

I need to save and load the cookies. Also must send a post data. 
So, how i do this? With "requests" or urllib or mechanize?

Many thx for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

To convert this curl into python, first you have to understand what are the commandline parameters doing here. You can easily check these from the [curl's man page](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html).

Now, to implement it in Python, the libraries you have mentioned are all capable to do it (except `urllib` or `urllib2`, its slightly harder compare to the other twos).

Here is [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6878418/putting-a-cookie-in-a-cookiejar) about how the `requests` is using cookiejar in combined with `cookielib` of Python. And here is [an example](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests) of how you can post data using `requests`. As you feel comfort with Python, you can easily combine these two into a single code I believe. If not, then show us what you have done so far and we can continue from there!

Comment: Thanks for your links, but that not helping me. Saving and loading cookies is not easy with cookiejar. Never two lines :/