# Using requests module, how to handle 'set-cookie' in request response?

Tags: python, cookies, python-requests

I'm attempting to open a login page (GET), fetch the cookies provided by the webserver, then submit a username and password pair to log into the site (POST).

Looking at [this Stackoverflow question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6878418/putting-a-cookie-in-a-cookiejar), I would think that I would just do the following:

```
import requests
from http.cookiejar import CookieJar

url1 = 'login prompt page'
url2 = 'login submission URL'
jar = CookieJar()

r = requests.get(url1, cookies=jar)
r2 = requests.post(url2, cookies=jar, data="username and password data payload")
```

However, in `r` there is a `Set-Cookie` in the headers, but that isn't changing the `jar` object.  In fact, nothing is being populated into `jar` as the linked question's response would indicate.

I'm getting around this in my code by having a headers dict and after doing the GET or POST, using this to handle the `Set-Cookie` header:

```
headers['Cookie'] = r.headers['set-cookie']
```

Then passing around the headers in the requests methods.  Is this correct, or is there a better way to apply the `Set-Cookie`?

Comment: The code in the answer you linked to [hasn't worked](https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/6117) since Requests 1.0.0, released in December 2012

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Ignore the cookie-jar, let `requests` handle cookies for you. Use a [`Session` object](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#session-objects) instead, it'll persist cookies and send them back to the server:

```
with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.get(url1)
    r = s.post(url2, data="username and password data payload")
```

Answer (score 14):

There's an included class called a [`session`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#session-objects) which automatically handles this sort of thing for you. You can create an instance of it, and then call `get` and `set` right on that instance instead.

```
import requests

URL1 = 'login prompt page'
URL2 = 'login submission URL'

session = requests.Session()

r = session.get(URL1)
r2 = session.post(URL2, data="username and password data payload")
```

Answer (score 6):

Another way that has worked for me (without using [session objects](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#session-objects)) is the following (tested in `v2.18.4`).

```
jar = requests.cookies.RequestsCookieJar()
response1 = requests.get(some_url, cookies=jar) # or post ...
jar.update(response1.cookies)
response2 = requests.get(some_other_url, cookies=jar) # or post ...
```

Note that the above code will fail in the presence of redirects which are handled transparently by the [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library. In such a case, you also have to update your jar with the cookies sent in the redirect responses. E.g. by doing something like the following:

```
if (response.history): # we have to add to the cookie jar, the cookies sent by the server in intermediate responses 
    for historicResponse in response.history:
        jar.update(historicResponse.cookies)
```