# Exceeding max redirects when attempting to scrape a webpage?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping

I'm attempting to scrape a webpage in Node.js.

```
var request = require('request').defaults({maxRedirects:3});


let url = "https://webapp4.asu.edu/catalog/classlist?k=81684&t=2177&e=all&hon=F&promod=F"
// , qs:propertiesObject
request({url:url}, function(err, response, body) {
  if(err) { console.log(err); return; }
  console.log("Get response: " + response.statusCode);
});
```

I'm getting max number of redirects for some reason. I can do a get request in `postman` and I can visit the page just fine. What would I do to cause redirects to happen?

Comment: Why are you passing the same query params in propertiesObject that are found in your url?  Most of the time you will have a url like "https://webapp4.asu.edu/catalog/classlist" and then you will pass a query object that is something like { k:'81684', t:'2177', e:"all", hon:"F", promod:"F" }.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. I didn't have that in the request.

Comment: And have you tried removing ".defaults({maxRedirects:3});" and does that change the outcome?  I believe the request default is 10, and depending on the page you are trying to view 3 may be too low.

Comment: Yes, I have tried that as well

Comment: Would it have anything to do with the referrer? I notice on the request they have a policy Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade

Comment: Try using cookieJar from `cookielib` https://stackoverflow.com/a/6930182/11686526

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best Pratice: You should always check for a robots.txt file before scraping a webpage.  I was unable to locate one for this specific site, but if you do come across a site that does not allow scraping you should follow all rules.

That being said, it seems as if your scraper is getting stuck in an infinite redirect loop due to the lack of headers on the outgoing request.

Something like the below will get you a response, but you will need to determine what parsing needs to be done to extract information from it.

```
var request = require('request');

var options = {
  url: 'https://webapp4.asu.edu/catalog/classlist?k=81684&t=2177&e=all&hon=F&promod=F',
  headers: {
    "method":"GET",
    "path":"/catalog/classlist?k=math&t=2177&e=all&hon=F&promod=F",
    "scheme":"https",
    "accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
    "accept-encoding":"gzip, deflate, sdch, br",
    "accept-language":"en-US,en;q=0.8",
    "cache-control":"no-cache",
    "cookie":"JSESSIONID=javaprod19~413DF4150236B1466C8ECB85EB796C06.catalog19; onlineCampusSelection=C; __cfduid=d5e9cb96f2485f7500fec2116ee8f23381491087061; __utma=59190898.1874896314.1491088625.1491088625.1491088625.1; __utmb=59190898.2.10.1491088625; __utmc=59190898; __utmz=59190898.1491088625.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); __utma=137925942.2000995260.1491087063.1491087063.1491088718.2; __utmb=137925942.2.10.1491088718; __utmc=137925942; __utmz=137925942.1491088718.2.2.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=(not%20provided); ADRUM=s=1491089349546&r=https%3A%2F%2Fwebapp4.asu.edu%2Fcatalog%2Fclasslist%3F-1275642430",
    "pragma":"no-cache",
    "referer":"https://webapp4.asu.edu/catalog/",
    "upgrade-insecure-requests":"1",
    "user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36"
  }
};

function callback(error, response, body) {

    console.log(response.body)

}
request(options, callback);
```

Comment: Interesting.. Is it possible to speed this up somehow? An application like postman retrieves the data instantly. I increased max redirects to 1200, still haven't gotten results yet,

Comment: Update: 1200 outputted "exceeded max redirects"

Comment: That is awesome! My only question is, the data in the res body is obfuscated. Is there a way around that? I can't even make out the symbols.

Comment: Got it! Thanks so much