# Python requests Too Many Redirects during web scraping?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web, web-scraping, python-requests

So i want to web scrape one site, but when i iterate over the results pages after few request(about 30 max.) requests.get throws this error:

> requests.exceptions.TooManyRedirects: Exceeded 30 redirects

The search url gets redirected to the main page url and each next url acts the same until I connect to different VPN.
Even when i am spoofing user agent and rotating proxies from a list of free proxies it still gets redirected after few requests. I have never had a problem during web scraping like that before. What is the best way to bypass this "redirect block"? 
***allow_redirects=False*** doesn't work here too.

```
import requests
import random
import time

agents = [...] # List of user agents

for i in range(1,100):
    url = "https://panoramafirm.pl/odpady/firmy,{}.html".format(i)
    r = requests.get(url, headers={"User-Agent": random.choice(agents)})
    print(r.status_code)
    time.sleep(random.randint(10,15))
```

Comment: Try using cookieJar from `cookielib` https://stackoverflow.com/a/6930182/11686526

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) you could make use of [`allow_redirects=False`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#redirection-and-history) option.

Comment: I tried it but it didn't help. After about 20 requests it starts redirecting back to home page status code is 302 for the redirected ones.

Comment: For some reason I get `This page isn’t working panoramafirm.pl redirected you too many times` error with even visiting the page - so I can't check right now - I'll try later and if I find a solution I'll post it!

Comment: That would be great. If you have VPN you could try accesing with one located in Poland(that worked for me when i first saw this page isn't working)