# Too many redirects and error 307 webscraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to scrape a website using this code:

```
url = 'https://www.seloger.com/list.htm?types=1%2C2&projects=2%2C5&natures=1%2C2%2C4&places=%5B%7Bdiv%3A2238%7D%5D&qsVersion=1.0&engine-version=new'

headers = {'User-Agent': '*',
'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
'Connection': 'keep-alive',
'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
}

import requests

s = requests.Session()
s.headers.update(headers)

r = s.get(url,allow_redirects=False)

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
```

I get None for soup. For r I get:

```
<Response [307]>
```

and for r.headers I get:

```
{'Cache-Control': 'private', 'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8', 
'Location': '/erreur-temporaire/', 'Vary': 'User-Agent', 'Server': 'Microsoft-IIS/8.5', 'Set-Cookie': 'ASP.NET_SessionId=noczxhxrmkqrmqso3opalin1; path=/; HttpOnly, Compte=; domain=.seloger.com; expires=Sat, 02-Jun-2018 09:34:11 GMT; path=/, SearchAnnDep=67; domain=.seloger.com; expires=Tue, 03-Jul-2018 09:34:11 GMT; path=/, __uzma=ma7e669aa2-ef5b-4b04-85b3-69085e096d7a2594; expires=Wed, 31-May-2028 09:34:11 GMT; path=/, __uzmb=1528025651; expires=Wed, 31-May-2028 09:34:11 GMT; path=/, __uzmc=871151037553; expires=Wed, 31-May-2028 09:34:11 GMT; path=/, __uzmd=1528025651; expires=Wed, 31-May-2028 09:34:11 GMT; path=/', 'X-S': 'X17, X17', 'Cache': 'max-age=10, max-age=10', 'X-Powered-By': 'ASP.NET', 'Date': 'Sun, 03 Jun 2018 09:34:11 GMT', 'Content-Length': '0'}
```

I understand there might be something to do with 'Locations' but I am not sure what...

Also i have added

```
allow_redirects=False
```

to s.get because I was getting a 'too many redirects' error...

Comment: Well when I `curl -I <your url>` I get a `307` response. Are you sure thats the right url?

Comment: Maybe try adding a proxy to the request url section

Comment: Road runner : the link used to work before I had the redirects problem... Another thing : now when I try to go to the website with my browser (chrome) I get tje same redirect problem.

Comment: Surya tej: wht do you mean? Also thanks for answering

Comment: Try using cookieJar from `cookielib` https://stackoverflow.com/a/6930182/11686526