# Python HTTP Request gets blocked

Tags: python, html, regex, httprequest

I have been trying to get through a request where the first page is a mathematical calculus to pass to the main page. This part is solved. However when I try to obtain something else i get the following:

```
<script>
window.location.reload();
</script>
```

I have learned this method in a while but only now I am trying it for the first time:

```
import re
import requests


def login_tokyo(s):
    r = s.get('https://apcis.tmou.org/public/')
    str_number = re.findall("<span[^>]+(.*?)</span>", r.text)[0]
    numbers = re.findall('[0-9]+', str_number)
    captcha = int(numbers[0]) + int(numbers[1])
    payload = {'captcha': captcha}
    r = s.post('https://apcis.tmou.org/public/?action=login', data=payload)
    check_text = re.findall('<b>(.*?)</b>', r.text)[0]
    print(check_text)
    payload1 = {'Param': 0, 'Value': 5797164, 'imo': '', 'callsign': '', 'name': '', 'compimo': 5797164,
                'compname': '', 'From': '01.06.2020', 'Till': '31.08.2020', 'authority': 0, 'flag': 0, 'class': 0,
                'ro': 0, 'type': 0, 'result': 0, 'insptype': -1, 'sort1': 0, 'sort2': 'DESC', 'sort3': 0,
                'sort4': 'DESC'
                }
    r = s.post('https://apcis.tmou.org/public/?action=getcompanies', data=payload1)
    perf_tm = re.findall("<p class=[^>]+(.*?)</p>", r.text)
    print(r.text)
    print(perf_tm)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with requests.Session() as s:
        login_tokyo(s)
```

The `print(check_text)` tells me that I am on the main page but then... nothing. From this specific request, I expected the `print(perf_tm)` to get me Medium.
Appreciate all help!

Comment: what information you need to scrape?

Comment: I love the math question captcha on the website, they are just as effective as spell.

Comment: I am trying to scrape the company performance @ZarakiKenpachi

Comment: btw I would highly recommend using postman/insomnia to manually test requests and checking which headers are required and which are not.

Comment: also if you are lazy like me, just copy the request from network tab in your browser as a cURL request and paste it here: https://curl.trillworks.com/

Comment: @Eduardo what is input data to get company data?

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi thanks for your attention. The answer from Anunay completely solved the problem :)

Comment: @Anunay I will look into that website. I have meanwhile downloaded Postman and will also try it out! Thanks again for all your inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT:

Nevermind, I was wrong, session should be handling all cookies, seems like the website rejects requests from borwsers without a User-Agent, just do this:

```
def login_tokyo(s):
    header={'User-Agent':''}
    s.headers.update(header)
    r = s.get('https://apcis.tmou.org/public/')
    str_number = re.findall("<span[^>]+(.*?)</span>", r.text)[0]
    ...
```

Orignal Answer:

You are not handling `PHPSESSID` cookie, many websites use it track logins serverside, try doing this

```
def login_tokyo(s):
    header={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.','Cookies':'PHPSESSID=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'}
    s.headers.update(header)
    r = s.get('https://apcis.tmou.org/public/')
    str_number = re.findall("<span[^>]+(.*?)</span>", r.text)[0]
    ...
```

You can also use [cookielib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/cookielib.html) (more info in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6878418/putting-a-cookie-in-a-cookiejar)), if you do not want to manually handle cookies, though most servers do not care if the sessionid set is already in their database, and would accept any random sessionid.

Comment: This worked like a charm. Thank you for identifying the issue. I will certainly learn more about it to understand it better.